# Information about supported http header values for recent browsers

Tags: security, http, header

Do you know if there is a site giving the list of supported http headers for every recent browser?

I'm wondering if 'x-frame-options' is really deprecated and already replaced by 'frame-ancestor' as indicated by W3C sites:

> The frame-ancestors directive obsoletes the X-Frame-Options header. If a resource has both policies, the frame-ancestors policy SHOULD be enforced and the X-Frame-Options policy SHOULD be ignored.

Comment: This was my very first question... But just after asking the question, I found an answer! The URL http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2 gives the answer I expected.